# How to rightly redirect file using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect my file using .htaccess, here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=404]
```

It shows an error saying:

> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How do I fix it?

if someone visit index.php >> they will get 404 error..
if someone visit index they will get the right one

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Your rule says anything not a `?` and not a space that contains `.php` and if that matches show a 404 not found page.

Comment: Please post all your rules; If these are all your rules, please edit in what mod_* is translating `index` to a file on your server. Please consult your error log to find out what internal server error occured while trying to load the 404 page. Could it be a php page? What do you want to happen if someone goes to `localhost/index`? What do you want to happen if someone goes to `localhost/index.php`?

Answer (score 2):

You might be having some `ErrorDocument` directive for 404 set somewhere in parent htaccess or on Apache config. Have it this way to set it back to default:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default    
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^?\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=404]
```